# Rounding Numbers away from 0 in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, math, rounding

I have done some research and found out the `Math.Round` and `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` methods.

The second method does what I want but I do not understand the syntax behind using it.

For example, if you have the `double` 5.5 and want to use normal rounding to get 6, and 4.4 to get 4, how would this be done?

Comment: Which language? (the tags say C, the title C# )

Comment: "and want to use normal rounding" ah, there's the crux... first define "normal" :)

Comment: Just a side-note: When rounding to an integer, `double` is fine. When rounding to decimal digits, you probably should use `decimal` instead.

Comment: `double` can't represent numbers like `0.1` exactly. `double` is great if small deviations don't matter, i.e. if you don't care if a number is `0.100000000001` or `0.9999999999999`. Midpoint rounding is meaningless, if you can't represent `1.15` exactly and want to round to one decimal digits. If decimal digits are important, and you want to talk about "This is exactly 0.1" then use decimal. Rounding to a specified amount of decimal digits, clearly indicates that you should use `decimal` for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some [overloads of `Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx) take a [`MidpointRounding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx) value as a parameter.

You could therefore write:

```
Math.Round(2.225m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

and that expression would evaluate to `2.23`.

Comment: Note that if you're interested in decimal digits, `decimal` would usually be a better type to use than `double` anyway...

Comment: There is some documentation about this here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx

just to complement W0lfs answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right (of course); I've updated my answer to use a `decimal` instead.

Comment: Well it really depends. If you're doing currency calculations, then yes. If you're calculating a fourier transform, or the inverse of a large matrix, then no. Unless you want it to take thousands of times longer to calculate. You're also going to have problems doing any trig with Decimal... Context is everything :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson: If you're calculating a fourier transform, why would you care about something to a certain number of *decimal* places, or care about rounding of a decimal digit? I'm certainly not saying that `decimal` should be used in all cases - but if you find yourself caring about the exact digits in a *decimal* representation of a `double`, that should ring alarm bells.

Comment: I think CodeInChaos put it best in his comment above: if you cannot represent `someNumber.5` exactly, why would you care about the rounding behavior in the first place?